# Will "be" be natural in the sentence?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Hostage to another hostage:

> Calm down, okay? The police are negotiating with our captors. We'll
> soon **be** out of here.

Does the last sentence seem perfectly natural to you? Or would it only be natural if I had used "get" instead of "be"?

Comment: Either is fine, though I would prefer re-ordering: **We'll be out of here soon.**

Answer (score 1):

It is correct as is. To "get out" implies that the people trapped are taking action to escape. The hostages are waiting for the police to get *them* out, so they will soon *be* out of where they are.

I would agree with randomhead's comment that "We'll be out of here soon" is a little more natural. "Soon be" isn't wrong; it just sounds like the sort of thing you would write in a movie script rather than say spontaneously.